# Can't project/extend after `bag_unpack` if empty table

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm using `bag_unpack` to explode the `customDimensions` column in the AppInsights `traces` table and want to "shape" the resultant table. All is fine if there are rows to work with. If there are not, subsequent operations that reference the exploded columns fail. For example (I boiled it down to an isolated repro),

```
datatable (Date:datetime, JSON:string )
    [datetime(1910-06-11), '{"key": "1"}', datetime(1930-01-01), '{"key": "2"}',
     datetime(1953-01-01), '{"key": "3"}', datetime(1997-06-25), '{"key": "4"}']
| where Date > datetime(2000-01-01)
| project parsed = parse_json(JSON)
| evaluate bag_unpack(parsed)
| project-rename value = key
// lots more data shaping here
```

Since the `where` filters out all rows, there is nothing to unpack. OK, that's fine but the data shaping ops (e.g., `project-rename`) fail saying

> project-rename: Failed to resolve column reference 'key'

If you change the date in the `where` to be say `1900-01-01` then everything works as expected.

Note as well that if you remove the `bag_unpack` the `project-rename` some other column, it works fine with no rows. For example,

```
datatable (Date:datetime, JSON:string )
    [datetime(1910-06-11), '{"key": "1"}', datetime(1930-01-01), '{"key": "2"}',
     datetime(1953-01-01), '{"key": "3"}', datetime(1997-06-25), '{"key": "4"}']
| where Date > datetime(2000-01-01)
| project-rename value = JSON
```

I can see how the unpack creates the columns so if it didn't run the column doesn't get created but at the same time, why run the `project` at all if there are no rows?

In theory I could move the `where` down but I'm not sure if the query planning will recognize that and only do the subsequent project/data shaping on the reduced set of rows (filtered by the `where`). I've got a lot of rows and typically only need to operate on a few of them.

Pointers on how to work with `bag_unpack` and empty tables? Or columns that may or may not be there?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `column_ifexists()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/columnifexists

For example:

```
... | project value = column_ifexists("key", "")
```

Comment: Thanks @Yoni L. That would be fine but I have quite a few columns and it would get pretty messy. Also some of the shaping involves parsing/casting (parse_json, toreal, ...) so AFAICT I'd have to `project` using `ifexists` and then `extend` with the new value then `project-away` the old column and `project-rename` the new column. Yikes. It's almost as if I'd like to say "I know I don't add any rows so if the table's empty <here>, just return".

Honestly this feels like an issue in the query engine. It could check if there are any rows before evaluating the `project` args.